# PowerShell - Delete files by modified date in specific folders

Tags: powershell, delete-file

Reading to the source is not working or i'm not even sure if everything is working.. need your help guys.

Thanks!

```
$Src = C:\Users\Asus\Documents\PowerShell\Folder.txt

Get-ChildItem –Path $Src -file -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} | Remove-Item -Whatif
```

content on Folder.txt

```
New Folder

New Folder(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
$Src = "C:\Users\Asus\Documents\PowerShell\Folder.txt"
Get-ChildItem –Path (Get-Content $Src) -file -Recurse
```

Comment: ohh.. the syntax... the where-object is correct, right?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much... however, how can i use this command even if you are on the path c:\Users? it seems it's only work whenever i am on 'powershell' folder. i'm about to put this on task scheduler - you think it will work that way?

Comment: You would need the full path in your Folder.txt, or to write your line like: `Get-ChildItem –Path (Get-Content "C:\Destination\To\Search\$Src") -file -Recurse`

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Marcus, on the C: drive you may need the -Force parameter on the Remove-Item.